# Custom font works in Safari, IE. Fails in Chrome, FF and Opera

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts

I've got two custom fonts. Both fonts are working fine on Safari (OSX and IOS) And Chrome and firefox on iOS and IE11. Font 'Underwood' fails on Chrome, Firefox and Opera on OSX with error "Failed to decode downloaded font". Font 'Avenir' works on every browser.

Font is hosted locally. I have tried both a relative and a absolute path. I have downloaded an alternative 'underwood' and converted ttf to otf. All to no avail.

Anybody a solution?

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Avenir';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: url('fonts/Avenir/avenir-light.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/Avenir/avenir-light.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'Underwood';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: url('//www.dekipgallery.nl/includes/fonts/Underwood/Underwood.eot');
src: url('//www.dekipgallery.nl/includes/fonts/Underwood/Underwood.woff') format('woff'),
     url('//www.dekipgallery.nl/includes/fonts/Underwood/Underwood.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('//www.dekipgallery.nl/includes/fonts/Underwood/Underwood.otf') format('opentype'),
     url('//www.dekipgallery.nl/includes/fonts/Underwood/Underwood.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('//www.dekipgallery.nl/includes/fonts/Underwood/Underwood.svg#my_underwoodregular') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in console?

Comment: Failed to decode downloaded font <path to font>